# Products of eigenfunctions on compact Riemann surfaces

Tags: rt.representation-theory, riemannian-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, riemann-surfaces, laplacian

Let $M$ be a compact Riemann surface with genus $g\geq 2$, endowed with the Riemannian metric with constant sectional curvature $-1$. Let $f_1, f_2$ be two (global) eigenfunctions for the Laplace-Beltrami operator. Clearly the product $f_1\cdot f_2$ admits a series expansion in terms of other eigenfunctions.

My questions are the following:

1. Is the series, by any chance, involves only finitely many eigenfunctions? Is there any known concrete example of expansion that supports or disproves this?
2. Is there any relations between the coefficient in the series and representation theory?

In case $M$ is the sphere with positive sectional curvature, or $M$ is the torus with zero sectional curvature, we know that $f_1\cdot f_2$ is indeed a finite linear combination of eigenfunctions. For the spherical case, the coefficient is determined by the Clebsch-Gordan rules. For torus case, the coefficient is determined by certain structures on a lattice. I am wondering if similar facts hold in higher genus surfaces.

Comment: I don't think so. You can have hyperbolic surfaces given by the quotient of the upper half plane by a congruence subgroup corresponding to a maximal order of a division algebra, and then eigenfunctions are simply Maass forms for this surface. The spectral expansion of $f_1 f_2$ in terms of other eigenfunctions involves the triple products $\langle f_1 f_2, f\rangle$. By the Watson-Ichino triple product formula, the square of the absolute value of this can be expressed in terms of a triple product $L$-function. This can vanish for "trivial" reasons (due to the root number being $-1$)...

Comment: ...but for half of the Maass forms, these shouldn't vanish, and one can prove via methods of analytic number theory that most of these triple products don't vanish; certainly infinitely many don't vanish. The representation theory underlying this is that of invariant trilinear functionals on $\mathrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{R})$; for the sphere, instead you work with $\mathrm{SO}(3)$.

Comment: Thanks! I believe this answers my question. Would you mind to provide some good references for me to further explore the terminologies you mentioned?

Comment: Watson's thesis: https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.0425v3. Ichino's paper: https://doi.org/10.1215/00127094-2008-052. In general, this area of number theory is not so accessible in the literature, in my experience. There are several papers by Bernstein and Reznikov (or by Reznikov alone) that are also quite relevant.

Comment: I forgot to mention: on a sphere, the spectral expansion of $f_1 f_2$ involves only finitely many eigenfunctions since $\langle f_1 f_2, f\rangle = 0$ if the degree of $f$ is larger than the sum of the degrees of $f_1$ and $f_2$ (where by degree I mean the degree of the harmonic polynomial corresponding to the spherical harmonic). On (a quotient of) the upper half plane, we instead have that $\langle f_1 f_2, f\rangle$ is exponentially small if the eigenvalue of $f$ is sufficiently large compared to $f_1$ and $f_2$.

Comment: I guess this means that in general the series involves infinitely many eigenfunctions, though the coefficient is decaying exponentially as eigenvalue gets large.

Comment: It would be interesting to know how fast the coefficients decay.

Comment: @clvolkov Yes, and this is be rigorously proveable in the setting you're interested in: $|\langle f_1 f_2,f\rangle|^2$ can be written as a certain product of gamma functions times some factor $|c_{f_1,f_2,f}|^2$. Stirling's formula tells you the behaviour of the gamma functions, which gives you the explicit exponential decay, while the factor $|c_{f_1,f_2,f}|^2$ can be shown to be bounded on average. See https://doi.org/10.17323/1609-4514-2004-4-1-19-37